# Flex-basis флексбокс адаптация

Tags: html, css

Как адаптивно с помощью FlexBox без использования медиазапросов сверстать такие блоки? Чтобы при ресайзе они адаптивно изменяли ширину, и минимальная ширина была 20%, пытался через flex-basis но кажется я не до конца понимаю суть флексов, примеры смотрел.
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `min-width:20%;`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать `flex`-контейнеру `flex-wrap: wrap`, а `flex-элементам` минимальную ширину и фикс.ширину, чтобы переносилось всё:

```css
.flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  min-width: 20%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-cont">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```